# getting this type of error "Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found ')' at line 20 column 23 "

Tags: apex, batch

Here is my complete code sample

```
global class b1 implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

 global final string query;
 global final string s_object;
 global final string field;
 global final string field_value;

 global b1 (string q, string s, string f, string v){
       Query =q;
       s_object=s;
       field = f;
      field_value =v;
   }

  global Database.QueryLocator start (Database.BatchableContext BC){
  return Database.getQueryLocator (query);
  }

  global void excute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> batch) {
  for(s_object o= batch){
  o.put(field,field_valu);

  }
  update batch;
  }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of code

```
global void excute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> batch) {
  for(s_object o: batch)  // use colon here
  { 
     o.put(field,field_valu);

  }
    update batch;
  }
```

Your error will be solved.

Comment: yaa its solved thank uuu sharma

Comment: @seenuChinnavangali if your problem solved then you can accept this answer and close this question.

Comment: 1.5 year old answer down voted without any comments. At least tell me the reason.